# Why my instance variable is not initialized by @Inject giving null?

Tags: java, guice

A.java

```
Class A(){
    Para1 para1;
    Para2 para2;     // Getting proper Value no issue with this.
    private void method_A(){
         int sortField = service.getValue();    // Getting proper value no issue.
         if(sortField == null){
         DefaultGridPanel df = new DefaultGridPanel(para1, para2);    // Issue is in this.
         }
    }
}
```

DefaultGridpanel.java

```
public class DefaultGridPanel{

     @Inject
     private transient Provider < ApplicationInstance > appInstanceProvider;

     public DefaultGridPanel(){
        //
        //Constructor Some intialization
        System.out.print(appInstanceProvider);
        setPageSize(getRecordsPerPage());
    }

    private Integer getRecordsPerPage() {
        ApplicationInstance appInstance = appInstanceProvider.get();
   //------------Here-------------
   // appInstanceProvider getting null and throwing nullpointerException.
        Integer recordsPerPage = 0;
        if (appInstance != null) {
            recordsPerPage = appInstance.getRecordsPerPage();
        }
        if (recordsPerPage != null && recordsPerPage > 0) {
            return recordsPerPage;
        }
        else {
            return Preferences.DEFAULT_RECORDS_PER_PAGE;
        }
    }

}
```

Why I am not able initialized appInstanceProvider with @Inject
For This I am writing J unit

Approach 1) I am calling **method_A** with create new object.
I go through many questions on stack overflow and blogs.

I got that new Keyword will not able help me too work on with @Inject

Approach 2) I have try to override configure() and in that bind the appInstanceProvider. but still I am getting null.

Kindly tell me any kind of new approach or work around.

Comment: The DI context will inject you the needed instances. Do not create them yourself!

Comment: most likely because you don't use DI to have DefaultGridPanel instantiated

Answer (score 0):

So that `@Inject` works, `class A` must be managed. In this class, do not instantiate `DefaultGridPanel`. Instead inject it as well. 
The only problem I see is the use of parameterized constructor. Use setters to set these values.